# Problems with IF condition

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm trying to make a website that gathers information from APIs. The following code always evaluates to 'Beep Boop Beep! I can\t find the Wikipedia page with the API! :-( \n Anyways here is more info on...'! Anyone have any ideas why?

```
                var geoNamesWiki = result.geoNamesWiki;
                for (let j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                    if (geoNamesWiki.geonames[j].feature == 'country' &&
                        (geoNamesWiki.geonames[j].countryCode == openCage.results[0].components["ISO_3166-1_alpha-2"] ||
                            geoNamesWiki.geonames[j].title.includes(openCage.results[0].components.country))) {
                        $('#summary').html(geoNamesWiki.geonames[j].summary);
                        $('#wikiLink').html(geoNamesWiki.geonames[j].wikipediaUrl).attr("href", "https://" + geoNamesWiki.geonames[j].wikipediaUrl);
                    } else {
                        $('#summary').html('Beep Boop Beep! I can\t find the wikipedia page with the API! :-( \n Anyways here is more info on' + openCage.results[0].components.country + ':');
                        $('#wikiLink').html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + encodeURI(openCage.results[0].components.country)).attr("href", 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + encodeURI(openCage.results[0].components.country));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What is the value of `geoNamesWiki`?

Comment: geoNamesWiki is a json array of 30 entries with information for each country returned by geoNames, which can be found here: http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearch?q=london&maxRows=10&username=demo

Comment: Also when I delete the 'else' part of this statement it then works fine. This is to help when geoNames can't find the wikipedia entry (for some reason it can't find the wiki entry for Spain?! But most other countries are fine)

Answer (score 0):

Is suspect you have a *string* there at `var geoNamesWiki = result.geoNamesWiki;`
Try parsing it to a JSON object first `var geoNamesWiki = JSON.parse( result.geoNamesWiki );`

Comment: It's already a JSON object once it gets to this stage

Comment: Than there is a chance that you are overwriting everything evaluated so far with the else condition finale.

Comment: @LauraElizabeth so it was the `else` condition overwriting everything previously found, wasn't it?  :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to @Bekim Bacaj! I was overwriting what I had already done, so just needed to add a break on the final line of the IF part.